# Relation between the size of the smallest $\varepsilon$-covering of an infinite totally bounded set and its finite subsets

Tags: metric-spaces

Let $(X, d)$ be a metric space and $A \subseteq X$ a totally bounded subset. We call $\Gamma = \{U_i\}_{i=1}^n$ an $\varepsilon$-covering of $A$, if $A \subseteq \bigcup_{i=1}^n U_i$ and $diam(U_i) \leq 2\varepsilon$ for all $i = 1,\dots,n$. For such a set we may define the quantity $\mathcal N_\varepsilon(A)$, which is the smallest possible size of an $\varepsilon$-covering. My question can now be phrased as follows:

Suppose $A \subseteq X$ is an infinite totally bounded set. Does there exist a finite subset $B \subseteq A$ such that $\mathcal N_\epsilon(A) = \mathcal N_\epsilon(B)$

If $\mathcal N_\epsilon(A) = 1$, this is trivial. It is also is easy to prove that this is true when $\mathcal N_\epsilon(A) = 2$. Simply note that $A$ itself can't be an $\varepsilon$-covering of $A$ since $\mathcal N_\epsilon(A) > 1$. Therefore $diam(A) > 2\varepsilon$, which implies that there exist two elements $x$ and $y$ in $A$ with $d(x, y) > 2\varepsilon$. Finally let $B = \{x, y\}$. Clearly $\mathcal N_\epsilon(B) = 2$. Unfortunately I couldn't succeed in finding a similar proof for higher values of $\mathcal N_\epsilon(A)$. Is this even true?

Comment: Do you know a little about this notion and you're seeking an answer to a question that an expert might know and you're curious about, or is this an exercise in a book? If the former, then I'd start by looking at the first few pages of Kolmogorov/Tikhomirov's survey paper. (The first few pages are not all that advanced or difficult to follow.) See the link I gave in my answer to [Size of a function space](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3517466/13130).

Comment: I was actually studying that text and wanted to find an easier proof for the right-continuity of the absolute entropy function. The text mentions a "discrepancy" metric for measuring distances between sets. I don't know which metric the author refers to (don't have the referenced book), so before looking into that I wanted to find an alternative proof. If I can prove my claim above, then the right-continuity is easy to establish because it is simple to show for finite sets.

Comment: I don't have a copy of that book, but I do have a photocopy (not a digital copy) of the English translation that was published in **American Mathematical Society Translations** (2) 17 (1961), pp. 3-86. Theorem III (bottom of p. 281, proved on pp. 281-282) right continuity of four closely related functions is stated. The proof given doesn't seem to employ the short-cut you're attempting, and given that Kolmogorov and Tihomirov were the authors, my guess is that it's not possible to prove your way. If you'd like, I can email scans of 3 or 4 relevant pages, **(continued)**

Comment: but since my printer's feeder tray is not working, I can only scan one page at a time, hence I don't want to scan all 83 pages (then attach 83 separate files to an email). [Send me an email](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/13130/dave-l-renfro?tab=profile) if you want those pages, since your profile doesn't given your email.